# Unity Native c++ plugin memory usage

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, taskmanager, resource-monitor

I am allocating memory from my c++ plugin in Unity but I'm not sure if it is working correctly.

When I allocate ~25Gb(for testing purposes) of memory, it appears (according tho the windows task manager) that my memory is not being allocated. I then check the resource monitor and find that it says unity is using ~25Gb or memory?

Why is this?

also Paging file is set to 0.

[image]

Comment: `Commit` is the virtual address space reserved by the program.  The program does not get allocated physical pages of memory until you read or write an address on each page. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging

Comment: ah I see now, I set all the array elements to 0, and I see the space being used in the task manager. thanks